# How to send an email containing Greek characters using TIdMessage and Delphi XE *UPDATED*

Tags: delphi, email, character-encoding, indy

We want to send through email, using D-XE and Indy's `TIdMessage` component the following htm file as body:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1253">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    color:black;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:10.0pt;}
@page Section1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:72.0pt 90.0pt 72.0pt 90.0pt;}
div.Section1
    {page:Section1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor=white lang=EL>

<div class=Section1>

<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US style='font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>Abcd</span><span
lang=EN-US style='font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> </span><span
style='font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>αβγδ ά&#8118;&#8048;&#7938; </span></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

(Ok, the actual file is different but the problem is the same).

In the above file, if you'll save it as temp.htm and load it in the Internet Explorer, you'll see 4 latin characters, 4 Greek characters without tone and 4 Greek characters with tone (variations of Alpha - the first letter of Greek alphabet). Something like this:

**Abcd αβγδ άᾶὰἂ**

So far, so good.

If we load the above file in the `Body` property of the `TIdMessage` and send it through email it shows like this:

**Abcd ???? ?ᾶὰἂ**

As you see, the greek letters from the monotonic alphabet are replaced with ???? ? - tested using Mozilla Thunderbird 3 on WinXP.

The properties of the `TIdMessage` component are as follows:

[image: TIdMessage Properties]

I tried to set the `CharSet` to `Windows-1253` but no luck.

*Any ideas how this can work?*

UPDATE:

Answering your questions:

The raw message source *after* it was received is: (the email addresses were redacted)

```
From - Thu Sep 15 11:11:06 2011
X-Account-Key: account3
X-UIDL: 00007715
X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00400000
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
Return-Path: [redacted]
X-Envelope-To: [redacted]
X-Spam-Status: No, hits=0.0 required=5.0
    tests=AWL: 0.194,BAYES_20: -0.73,HTML_MESSAGE: 0.001,
    MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY: 0.56,MIME_HTML_ONLY: 0.001,MISSING_MID: 0.001,
    CUSTOM_RULE_FROM: ALLOW,TOTAL_SCORE: 0.027,autolearn=no
X-Spam-Level: 
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1])
    by [redacted]
    for [redacted];
    Thu, 15 Sep 2011 11:10:59 +0300
From: [redacted]
Subject: Test msg
To: [redacted]
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Sender: [redacted]
Reply-To: [redacted]
Disposition-Notification-To: [redacted]
Return-Receipt-To: [redacted]
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 11:10:59 +0300

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1253">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    color:black;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:10.0pt;}
@page Section1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:72.0pt 90.0pt 72.0pt 90.0pt;}
div.Section1
    {page:Section1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor=white lang=EL>

<div class=Section1>

<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US style='font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>Abcd</span><span
lang=EN-US style='font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> </span><span
style='font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>???? ?&#8118;&#8048;&#7938; </span></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Mozilla Thunderbird says also `Message Encoding: Western (ISO-8859-1)`. I tried to put in the `IdMessage` component different encodings like windows-1253 (Greek) or UTF-8 - the result was the same. Also, I tried to convert the htm file to UTF-8 (using the Notepad++) - it looked the same (I changed the charset by hand in the html's `meta` info). Sent the message again. The result: Abcd ???2?3?? ??ᾶὰἂ

Comment: Was the HTML file saved with the same Encoding which is shown in the meta header? I would also try to use UTF-8 and check if the problem still exists in the current 10.5.8 release of Indy. Finally, I would try to intercept (save to file or 'debug') the outgoing SMTP message and check which encoding it actually uses.

Comment: Could you post the raw RFC2822 message *after* it is received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your own screenshots, you will see that `TIdMessage` and the transmitted email are both set to use `US-ASCII` as the CharSet.  That is why your data is getting altered.

If you load the HTML into the `TIdMessage.Body` or `TIdText.Body` property, you have to decode the data to `UTF-16` (since that is what the `Body` property uses in XE) and then set the `TIdMessage.CharSet` or `TIdText.CharSet` property to `windows-1253` so the `UTF-16` data gets re-encoded properly when the email is sent, eg:

```
Enc := CharsetToEncoding('windows-1253');
try
  IdMessage.Body.LoadFromFile('file.htm', Enc);
  IdMessage.ContentType := 'text/html';
  IdMessage.CharSet := 'windows-1253';
finally
  Enc.Free;
end;
```

Or:

```
Enc := CharsetToEncoding('windows-1253');
try
  with TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, nil) do
  begin
    Body.LoadFromFile('file.htm', Enc);
    ContentType := 'text/html';
    CharSet := 'windows-1253';
  end;
finally
  Enc.Free;
end;
```

If you load the HTML into a TIdAttachment object instead, then you don't have to decode/encode anything manually, since the attachment data is sent as-is.

```
with TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, 'file.htm') do
begin
  ContentType := 'text/html';
end;
```

Comment: I believe the attachment technique is now the defacto standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ContentTransferEncoding, for example to quoted-printable. Remember that mail still uses 7-bit charcters (unless a server advertise it can handle 8-bit or binary data), thereby a proper transfer encoding is needed.

Comment: Did it. No luck. Thanks for the hint tough.

Answer (score 0):

I use Indy 10 and Delphi XE2 (Unicode std Strings)
setting Message CharSet to 'ISO-8859-7' and adding text to body using UTF8Encode

`TempMess := TIdMessage.Create(self); 
TempMess.CharSet          :='ISO-8859-7';
TempMess.Body.Add(UTF8Encode('Καλημέρα!!!'));`